# Spring BeanPostProcessor can not create proxy when beanPostProcessor is depend on target?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, cglib

I am stuck in this problem for a while and can not sleep:C

when I use beanPostProcessor to create proxy for a beanA(beanPostProcessor not depend on beanA), proxy works well.But if beanPostProcessor depend on beanA,it not work.And I found beanA is not proxied in Spring ApplicationContext when beanPostProcessor is depend on it

TargetIface:

```
public interface TargetIface {
    void work();
}
```

TargetA:

```
public class TargetA implements TargetIface {
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("targetA is working...");
    }
}
```

TargetB:

```
public class TargetB implements TargetIface {
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("targetB is working...");
    }
}
```

SimpleAdivsor:

```
public class SimpleAdvisor extends DefaultPointcutAdvisor {

private TargetIface targetIface;

private final Advice advice = new MethodInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("advice intercept....");
        if (invocation.getThis().equals(targetIface)) {
            System.out.println("my advice");
        }
        //no adivce
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
};

public SimpleAdvisor() {
    setAdvice(advice);
}

public void setTargetIface(TargetIface targetIface) {
    this.targetIface = targetIface;
}
}
```

beanPostProcessor:

```
public class ProxyProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {


private List<Advisor> advisors;

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof TargetIface) {
        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
        proxyFactory.setTarget(bean);
        proxyFactory.addAdvisors(advisors);

        return proxyFactory.getProxy();
    }
    return bean;
}

public void setAdvisors(List<Advisor> advisors) {
    this.advisors = advisors;
}
}
```

mainClass:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/Application-context.xml");
    TargetA targetA = context.getBean(TargetA.class);
    targetA.work();
```

first case:proxyBeanProcessor not depend on targetA

```
<bean id="proxyBeanProcessor" class="net.fendar.test.spring.processor.ProxyProcessor">
    <property name="advisors">
        <list>
            <bean class="net.fendar.test.spring.advisor.SimpleAdvisor">
                <!--<property name="targetIface" ref="targetA"/>-->
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="targetA" class="net.fendar.test.spring.bean.TargetA"/>
<bean id="targetB" class="net.fendar.test.spring.bean.TargetB"/>
```

output:

```
advice intercept....
targetA is working...
```

bean in applicationContext[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu7TL.png)

second case:proxyBeanProcessor depend on Target,

```
<bean id="proxyBeanProcessor" class="net.fendar.test.spring.processor.ProxyProcessor">
    <property name="advisors">
        <list>
            <bean class="net.fendar.test.spring.advisor.SimpleAdvisor">
                <property name="targetIface" ref="targetA"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="targetA" class="net.fendar.test.spring.bean.TargetA"/>
<bean id="targetB" class="net.fendar.test.spring.bean.TargetB"/>

<bean id="proxyBeanProcessor" class="net.fendar.test.spring.processor.ProxyProcessor">
    <property name="Target" ref="Target"/>
</bean>
```

output:

```
targetA is working...
```

bean in application:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/079XI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `BeanPostProcessor` bean depends on the bean you want to proxy

```
<bean id="proxyBeanProcessor" class="net.fendar.test.spring.processor.ProxyProcessor">
    <property name="Target" ref="Target"/>
</bean>
```

then that bean must necessarily be created before your `ProxyProcessor` bean is ready. And, if it's not ready, then there's no way it can post process any other beans, including your target bean.

---

When Spring initializes your beans, it passes them through all registered `BeanPostProcessor` bean instances. This implies that the `BeanPostProcesser` beans have already been initialized. Your case demonstrates a scenario where a bean is initialized before a `BeanPostProcessor`, which therefore can't process it.

Comment: tkx，I have tried to depend on other bean(not target bean) and proxy worked when calling the target.work() method.Only depending on target not works

Comment: @fendar It's all about the order of initialization here. If your `BeanPostProcessor` was initialized fully before the target, then it **can** post process it. If the `BeanPostProcessor` is not fully initialized because it's depending on the target, then it **cannot** post process it.

Comment: @fendar It's not clear what your problem is. Your `ProxyProcessor` doesn't need the `target` in the example you've shown.

Comment: sry for reply lately,I have edited my question to show the dependency;SimpleAdvisor do advice not on each TargetIface,so SimpleAdvisor needs to know which target should be advised